# Flex Slider full height and width without stretching

Tags: height, flexslider, stretching

I need Flex Slider to occupy the entire page, like the one on this website: http://webfire.co.uk/

I've set both height and width to 100%, but when I re-size the page, it causes the image to distort and stretch. However, setting the height to auto leaves a white space underneath the slider, so it doesn't fill up the full page. The same thing happens with background-size:cover - the width becomes responsive but the height stays the same.

On the website above, they manage to sort of re-center the image when the window is re-sized.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Do you have a link to your attempt? Would make it easier to debug.

Comment: I don't I'm afraid, I've been working locally. I can send pictures or code though?